# Installing packages by importing the list with dpkg --set-selections

Tags: software-installation, apt, dpkg

I've tested this using two virtual machines running Lubutu.

On the first I Installed a couple of programmes (VIM and cowsay) then ran :

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
sudo dpkg --get-selections > /home/klak/my_package_list.txt
```

[Here's what my_package_list.txt looks like](http://pastebin.com/y7xNxX7Y)

Then I booted into another VM that was a clone of the previous one prior to the VIM and cowsay installs and ran the following :

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
sudo apt-get install dselect
sudo apt-get dselect update

sudo dpkg --set-selections < ./my_package_list.txt && sudo apt-get -u dselect-upgrade
```

However I would now expect to be able to load VIM or use cowsay, but I get :

```
klak@klakBox:/media/share$ vim
The program 'vim' can be found in the following packages:
 * vim
 * vim-gnome
 * vim-tiny
 * vim-athena
 * vim-gtk
 * vim-nox
Try: sudo apt-get install <selected package>
klak@klakBox:/media/share$ cowsay "boo"
The program 'cowsay' is currently not installed. You can install it by typing:
sudo apt-get install cowsay
```

It went through a load of install process when I ran the the above commands, so I'm not sure why this hasn't worked.

Cheers!

### Edit 1

Not sure why this errors (it seems to be a valid `dselect` option) :

```
klak@klakBox:/media/share$ sudo apt-get dselect update
E: Invalid operation dselect
klak@klakBox:/media/share$
```

#### Edit 1.1

There's a CLI menu for dselect if I just enter `sudo dselect`, I'm not sure how I would include this into a script though. 
From this menu I have chosen `update` (as the previous attempt to update failed)

- Note -> the first time I ran `sudo dselect update` was from a python script using `os.system("sudo dselect update")` -> Perhaps this errored silently, I don't know.

### Edit 2

I have used the following ([taken from here](http://www.childsplay.mobi/blog/?p=197))

```
dpkg --set-selections < selections.txt

$ sudo apt-get install dselect
$ sudo dselect 
   -> Update
   -> Install
```

The update and install for dselect are from within a CLI menu :

[image]

- I'm not sure how to script this
- I'm not sure If I should start another question, or whether this is really a satisfactory solution to the original problem?

Thanks.

### Edit 3

Here is the apt history that I've been asked for :

```
Start-Date: 2014-12-27  15:47:18
Commandline: apt-get upgrade
Upgrade: bind9-host:amd64 (9.9.5.dfsg-4.3, 9.9.5.dfsg-4.3ubuntu0.1), liblwres90:amd64 (9.9.5.dfsg-4.3, 9.9.5.dfsg-4.3ubuntu0.1), libsystemd-login0:amd64 (208-8ubuntu8, 208-8ubuntu8.1), libgnutls-openssl27:amd64 (3.2.16-1ubuntu2, 3.2.16-1ubuntu2.1), ppp:amd64 (2.4.5-5.1ubuntu3, 2.4.5-5.1ubuntu3.1), multiarch-support:amd64 (2.19-10ubuntu2, 2.19-10ubuntu2.1), libdns100:amd64 (9.9.5.dfsg-4.3, 9.9.5.dfsg-4.3ubuntu0.1), oxideqt-codecs-extra:amd64 (1.2.5-0ubuntu1, 1.3.4-0ubuntu0.14.10.1), libisccfg90:amd64 (9.9.5.dfsg-4.3, 9.9.5.dfsg-4.3ubuntu0.1), python3-cupshelpers:amd64 (1.5.1+20141010-0ubuntu2, 1.5.1+20141010-0ubuntu2.1), libbind9-90:amd64 (9.9.5.dfsg-4.3, 9.9.5.dfsg-4.3ubuntu0.1), tcpdump:amd64 (4.6.2-1ubuntu1, 4.6.2-1ubuntu1.1), dbus:amd64 (1.8.8-1ubuntu2, 1.8.8-1ubuntu2.1), libgnutls-deb0-28:amd64 (3.2.16-1ubuntu2, 3.2.16-1ubuntu2.1), firefox-locale-en:amd64 (33.0+build2-0ubuntu0.14.10.1, 34.0+build2-0ubuntu0.14.10.2), whoopsie:amd64 (0.2.39, 0.2.39ubuntu0.1), dkms:amd64 (2.2.0.3-1.1ubuntu5, 2.2.0.3-1.1ubuntu5.14.10), gir1.2-gtk-3.0:amd64 (3.12.2-0ubuntu15, 3.12.2-0ubuntu15.1), firefox:amd64 (33.0+build2-0ubuntu0.14.10.1, 34.0+build2-0ubuntu0.14.10.2), libsystemd-daemon0:amd64 (208-8ubuntu8, 208-8ubuntu8.1), libgudev-1.0-0:amd64 (208-8ubuntu8, 208-8ubuntu8.1), libc-dev-bin:amd64 (2.19-10ubuntu2, 2.19-10ubuntu2.1), chromium-codecs-ffmpeg-extra:amd64 (37.0.2062.94-0ubuntu1~pkg1065, 39.0.2171.65-0ubuntu0.14.10.1.1106), mountall:amd64 (2.54build1, 2.54ubuntu0.14.10.1), libpam-systemd:amd64 (208-8ubuntu8, 208-8ubuntu8.1), libc-bin:amd64 (2.19-10ubuntu2, 2.19-10ubuntu2.1), libc6:amd64 (2.19-10ubuntu2, 2.19-10ubuntu2.1), libglib2.0-0:amd64 (2.42.0-2, 2.42.1-1~ubuntu1), xserver-xorg-core:amd64 (1.16.0-1ubuntu1, 1.16.0-1ubuntu1.2), flashplugin-installer:amd64 (11.2.202.411ubuntu1, 11.2.202.425ubuntu0.14.10.1), libgtk-3-bin:amd64 (3.12.2-0ubuntu15, 3.12.2-0ubuntu15.1), dnsutils:amd64 (9.9.5.dfsg-4.3, 9.9.5.dfsg-4.3ubuntu0.1), libdbus-1-3:amd64 (1.8.8-1ubuntu2, 1.8.8-1ubuntu2.1), udev:amd64 (208-8ubuntu8, 208-8ubuntu8.1), system-config-printer-common:amd64 (1.5.1+20141010-0ubuntu2, 1.5.1+20141010-0ubuntu2.1), xserver-common:amd64 (1.16.0-1ubuntu1, 1.16.0-1ubuntu1.2), libglib2.0-data:amd64 (2.42.0-2, 2.42.1-1~ubuntu1), libflac8:amd64 (1.3.0-2, 1.3.0-2ubuntu0.14.10.1), gir1.2-gudev-1.0:amd64 (208-8ubuntu8, 208-8ubuntu8.1), libwhoopsie0:amd64 (0.2.39, 0.2.39ubuntu0.1), libappindicator3-1:amd64 (12.10.1+13.10.20130920-0ubuntu4, 12.10.1+13.10.20130920-0ubuntu4.2), ntp:amd64 (4.2.6.p5+dfsg-3ubuntu2, 4.2.6.p5+dfsg-3ubuntu2.14.10.1), libudev1:amd64 (208-8ubuntu8, 208-8ubuntu8.1), language-pack-gnome-en:amd64 (14.10+20141020, 14.10+20141205), xserver-xorg-video-intel:amd64 (2.99.914-1~exp1ubuntu4, 2.99.914-1~exp1ubuntu4.1), libgtk-3-0:amd64 (3.12.2-0ubuntu15, 3.12.2-0ubuntu15.1), libjasper1:amd64 (1.900.1-debian1-2, 1.900.1-debian1-2ubuntu0.1), libsystemd-journal0:amd64 (208-8ubuntu8, 208-8ubuntu8.1), systemd:amd64 (208-8ubuntu8, 208-8ubuntu8.1), libcurl3:amd64 (7.37.1-1ubuntu3, 7.37.1-1ubuntu3.1), libgtk-3-common:amd64 (3.12.2-0ubuntu15, 3.12.2-0ubuntu15.1), system-config-printer-gnome:amd64 (1.5.1+20141010-0ubuntu2, 1.5.1+20141010-0ubuntu2.1), dbus-x11:amd64 (1.8.8-1ubuntu2, 1.8.8-1ubuntu2.1), language-pack-en-base:amd64 (14.10+20141020, 14.10+20141205), libglib2.0-bin:amd64 (2.42.0-2, 2.42.1-1~ubuntu1), language-pack-gnome-en-base:amd64 (14.10+20141020, 14.10+20141205), linux-libc-dev:amd64 (3.16.0-24.32, 3.16.0-28.38), language-pack-en:amd64 (14.10+20141020, 14.10+20141205), libisccc90:amd64 (9.9.5.dfsg-4.3, 9.9.5.dfsg-4.3ubuntu0.1), libc6-dev:amd64 (2.19-10ubuntu2, 2.19-10ubuntu2.1), libisc95:amd64 (9.9.5.dfsg-4.3, 9.9.5.dfsg-4.3ubuntu0.1), libcurl3-gnutls:amd64 (7.37.1-1ubuntu3, 7.37.1-1ubuntu3.1), ntpdate:amd64 (4.2.6.p5+dfsg-3ubuntu2, 4.2.6.p5+dfsg-3ubuntu2.14.10.1)
End-Date: 2014-12-27  15:48:51

Start-Date: 2014-12-27  15:48:53
Commandline: apt-get install dselect
Install: dselect:amd64 (1.17.13ubuntu1)
End-Date: 2014-12-27  15:48:55

Start-Date: 2014-12-27  15:50:59
Commandline: /usr/bin/apt-get -f -oDir::State::status=/var/lib/dpkg/status -oDPkg::Options::=--admindir=/var/lib/dpkg dselect-upgrade
Install: linux-headers-3.16.0-28:amd64 (3.16.0-28.38, automatic), linux-image-3.16.0-28-generic:amd64 (3.16.0-28.38, automatic), linux-headers-3.16.0-28-generic:amd64 (3.16.0-28.38, automatic), linux-image-extra-3.16.0-28-generic:amd64 (3.16.0-28.38, automatic)
Upgrade: linux-headers-generic:amd64 (3.16.0.23.24, 3.16.0.28.29), linux-image-generic:amd64 (3.16.0.23.24, 3.16.0.28.29), linux-generic:amd64 (3.16.0.23.24, 3.16.0.28.29)
End-Date: 2014-12-27  15:52:26
```

The above history was from running the following commands (within python script):

import os

```
# This part is for reinstalling. 
os.system("sudo apt-get update")
os.system("sudo apt-get upgrade")
os.system("sudo apt-get install dselect")
#os.system("sudo dselect update")

os.system("sudo dpkg --set-selections < ./my_package_list.txt")
os.system("sudo dselect update")
os.system("sudo dselect install")
```

## Edit 4

This is the python script that works :

```
 os.system("sudo apt-get install dselect")
 os.system("sudo dselect update")
 os.system("sudo dpkg --set-selections < my_package_list.txt")
 os.system("sudo apt-get -y update")
 os.system("sudo apt-get dselect-upgrade")
```

Obviously prior to this being run there need to have been a package list created called `my_package_list.txt`, and it needs to be in the same directory as the Python file.

Comment: "It went through a load of install process" Paste that install process - at least the initial output from apt-get saying what it is going to do.

Comment: @FaheemMitha thanks I will. I'll do it from a fresh VM so it should be the same as the above -> the install process was quite large, the terminal history should scroll back far enough I guess. Would the whole thing be useful? I'll do that now.

Comment: To be clear, at the start it just says what it is going to install. Post that. Then there is a lot of output when it does actually install stuff. You don't need that. Also, you don't need to redo it, the log should be in `/var/log/apt/history.log`.

Comment: OK thanks @FaheemMitha i'll check, I exited and started cloning straight away. I'll have a look when it's finished in a few minutes.

Comment: @FaheemMitha I have edited the OP, some things worked differently to how I expected, let me know what you think. Cheers.

Comment: No, I meant the command line output of `apt-get`, saying what it is going to install. If I understood your question correctly, you want to know why things that were supposed to be installed were not installed, so the best way is to check and see what was installed.

Comment: @FaheemMitha I've updated the OP with history info and the commands that I ran.

Comment: It does not look like anything happened here. Don't run `apt-get` and similar Debian package system commands from within Python. These really should be run interactively from within a shell. The `dselect-upgrade` seems to have only attempted to install some linux kernel related stuff. I also don't understand your Python commands. You seem to be running "dselect install".

Comment: @FaheemMitha I'm just trying to piece together various things that I've found in order to automate the process of restoring the installed packages on a new system

Comment: Ok, but I don't understand why you have a "dselect install", for example.

Comment: @FaheemMitha just to make sure that it was on the system really. The idea is that I could run this script on a fresh system and it would install all of the packages from my old system

Comment: @FaheemMitha and chat isn't working for me btw - it logged me in with a different account, not sure why.

Comment: Ok, in any case, your `/usr/bin/apt-get -f -oDir::State::status=/var/lib/dpkg/status -oDPkg::Options::=--admindir=/var/lib/dpkg dselect-upgrade` is the main one. This does not seem to have installed much stuff. Did `dpkg --set-selections < ./my_package_list.txt` appear to have completed correctly?

Comment: You might not have enough rep for chat. I think you need 20.

Comment: @FaheemMitha re chat, fair enough! re 'main one' - I don't really follow. re `dpkg --set-selections < ./my_package_list.txt` : I'm not sure. I guess not because It didn't install VIM and VIM is in `my_package_list.txt`

Comment: @FaheemMitha thanks for your patience earlier - I have updated the OP (see edit #4) with a working version of the Python script. If you can see why it wasn't working previously or draw any lesson from this mess then it'd be nice to close the thread with an 'answer', I'm not too sure how to phrase it personally! I think it was related to the updating of dselect and the 4th line of the Python script. All a bit of a mess, i have some reading to do! cheers

Answer (score 13):

I created a process of doing that. So Every machine has the same packages.

I follow these steps:

First, retrieve the list of packages installed on the machine which will serve as the “model” to copy.

```
 dpkg --get-selections > pkg-list
```

In the new machine:
Update dpkg's database of known packages

```
 avail=`mktemp`
 apt-cache dumpavail > "$avail"
 dpkg --merge-avail "$avail"
 rm -f "$avail"
```

Update dpkg's selections

```
dpkg --set-selections < pkg-list
```

Ask apt-get to install the selected packages

```
apt-get dselect-upgrade
```

This works for me.

Comment: apt-cache dumpavail | dpkg --merge-avail may save you a temp file, no ?