# Backup and Restore list of installed packages and APT sources

Tags: ubuntu, software-installation, apt, package-management, dpkg

I commonly reinstall Ubuntu and back up my APT stuff [sources, keys and installed package lists] using the tutorial at https://askubuntu.com/a/99151/371765. However I commonly also remove software such as totem, transmission, unity scopes, etc.

When the install has finished and I restore my APT sources, keys, and installed packages from the previous install, I find I get the following:

1. I get a warning saying `dpkg: warning: package not in database at line ###: vlc` [vlc is an example, it could be `htop` or `iotop`]. I think it does this warning for every package to restore in the universe repos, however I am not too sure.
2. Anything uninstalled [totem, transmission, firefox, simple-scan, etc] on the previous system stays installed on the new system.

How can I make it so that anything uninstalled from the previous system gets uninstalled on the new system during installation of other packages [eg vlc]?

I have a made a start with diff plans, however when trying to convert version numbers to the word "test" [for testing purposes] in the Ubuntu 14.04.2 manifest, it converts all of the line and not a portion of it.

Comment: Please don't cross-post. Thanks for pointing it out but please delete the copies from AU and SU.

Answer (score 8):

A slight variation on [Installing packages by importing the list with dpkg --set-selections](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/176134/installing-packages-by-importing-the-list-with-dpkg-set-selections) should do the trick.

Save the list of packages on your reference system:

```
dpkg --get-selections > packages.lst
```

Then install packages based on that list on your target system, after updating the list of available packages:

```
dpkg --merge-avail <(apt-cache dumpavail)
dpkg --clear-selections
dpkg --set-selections < packages.lst
apt-get dselect-upgrade
```

Comment: I'll try that the next time I (re)install Ubuntu/Ubuntu distro

Comment: When running `sudo dpkg --merge-avail <(apt-cache dumpavail)` [sudo needed for write access], this error comes up: `Updating available packages info, using /dev/fd/63. dpkg: error: failed to open package info file /dev/fd/63 for reading: No such file or directory`. Any ideas why? Freshly installed system. EDIT: The third command does what 1. says in the question, probably because the first command failed.

Comment: You need to run the command substitution within the same shell as `dpkg`, so either become root beforehand, or run `sudo bash -c "dpkg --merge-avail <(apt-cache dumpavail)"`.

Comment: I was looking for a way to do a partial list. This is NOT it.

Comment: @cmcginty are you user100763?

Answer (score 1):

### Backup the packages installed

1. get the list of installed packages
2. remove those which where deinstalled
3. remove the installed column
4. save the list

```
# dpkg --get-selections | grep -v deinstall | awk '{print $1}' > package.lst
```

### Restore from package.lst

```
# aptitude install -y $(cat package.lst)
```