# Backup ubuntu configurations and deploy them later

Tags: ubuntu

How to take a backup of configurations like theme settings, font size, Network Manager connections, Touchpad settings etc. of my current Ubuntu 14.04 installation ?

I want to use them after installing latest 14.04.2 version. Is there any way to do this ?

Comment: Why not just upgrade to 14.04.2 without reinstalling?

Comment: Slow 2G interet, It will take ages to upgrade. I will download ubuntu 14.04.2 iso file on my phone.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most of your configuration is stored in `/etc` and in files in your home directory. So if you backup `/etc` and `/home` (which is a good idea anyway) you'll have everything you need to restore your settings after re-installing.

The rest of your configuration is in `/var`, but on Ubuntu that's configuration relating to what packages are installed; if you want to reproduce that you're better off running `dpkg --get-selections` and storing the output somewhere safe. You'll probably also want to run `apt-mark showauto` and store its output.

If your system has a separate partition or volume for `/home`, you can save yourself some bother by re-installing without formatting `/home`.

When restoring, follow the instructions at https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/190931 to restore the `dpkg` selections, then run `apt-mark auto $(< auto.backup)` to restore the `apt` package marks (where `auto.backup` is the file created earlier with `apt-mark showauto`). You shouldn't overwrite `/etc` with your backup, but compare the new version with your backup and apply any necessary changes: some files will have changed in the upgrade, and you don't want to overwrite those...